# Get selected values in a checkbox group in xpages

Tags: checkbox, xpages, selected

I have a checkbox group and I am trying to get the values ​​selected via SSJS, but so far I have not been successful. I've tried several syntaxes, such as:
    document1.getItemValueArray ("nameField")
and
    getComponent ("nameField") getSelectedValues ​​();

Does anyone know a way to get the selected values ​​from a checkbox group?

Comment: Do you have the checkbox group bound to "nameField"?  Can you add your checkbox markup?

Answer (score 1):

`document1.getFirstItem("nameField").getValues()` may be what you want. If it's one value, it will be a string, not a Vector, which may be *a* problem with `getItemValueArray()`.

With ODA (OpenNTF Domino API), we extended the `getItemValue()` method to take a second parameter and cast the result to that kind of object. That has a big benefit for this kind of scenario, allowing `getItemValue("nameField", ArrayList.class)` to *always* return an ArrayList even for a single value, plus ArrayList is a much better and more modern Java (so relevant also for SSJS) construct than a Vector.

Comment: The getFirstItem method does not exist for document1, which is of the NotesXspDocument class

Comment: `document1.getDocument(true).getFirstItem()` should get it, including UI updates

Comment: The new document does not yet have a notes document, nor a field.